# Как на <1200 (col-lg) дать колонке 100%, что бы она была под левой колонкой?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть такая структура :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2 ml-xl-auto"></div>
</div>
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы `.item-2` был по правой стороне до 1200, а потом получил 100% и спрыгнул под `.item-1`. Как это можно реализовать на Bootstrap? Мы используем Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="item-1 col-12 col-xl-4">Первый пункт</div>
  <div class="item-2 col-12 offset-xl-4 col-xl-4">второй пункт</div>
</div>
```

Для эффективной работы с bootstrap очень рекомендую ознакомиться с [grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) бутстрапа.